# Деплой сайта/бота на сервер через filezilla

Tags: python, сервер, веб-сервер, filezilla

Арендовал VPS сервер у Рег.ру (Минимальный пакет)
Я полный чайник в этой теме.
Пытаюсь подключиться к серверу как написано в методичке у рег.ру
Заканчивается все на том что критическая ошибка и не подключается к серваку
На серваке убунту стоит
Есть другие способы закинуть файлы на сервак? Чтоб было красиво, понятно как в реплите? А если нет, то помогите с файлзиллой. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: подключаешься по ssh?
напиши им в ТП с шагами что сделал - что получилось, должны помочь

Answer (score 0):

Для копирования файлов по SSH в Linux-системах и Windows используют разные инструменты:

- scp (Secure CoPy) — утилита для безопасного копирования данных между
  Linux-системами по протоколу SSH. Она входит в состав OpenSSH,
  поэтому для работы с утилитой не нужно устанавливать дополнительное
  ПО;
- pscp.exe — утилита для загрузки файлов по SSH в ОС Windows. Она
  обладает теми же возможностями, что и scp. Утилита входит в состав
  программы Putty — SSH-клиента для Windows. Скачать программу можно по
  [ссылке](https://putty.org.ru/download.html).

Скопировать файл по SSH с локальной машины на удалённый сервер:

> pscp [путь к файлу] [имя пользователя]@[имя сервера/ip-адрес]:[путь к файлу]

Скопировать файлы с удалённого сервера на локальный компьютер:

> pscp [имя пользователя]@[имя сервера/ip-адрес]:[путь к файлу] [путь к файлу]

Самый простой способ это через FileZilla:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В поле "Хост" вводите IP вашей VPS, в поле "Имя пользователя" вводите root, в поле "Пароль" вводите пароль указанный в панели управления VPS, в поле порт укажите 22. Затем нажмите "Быстрое соединение"